# Object tree in python vs DOM with Javascript

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I am trying to do some python app (Pyside/Qt), and can't figure how to proceed object as argument to another function. With Javascript I can access to any object/element in DOM. Does I need to build my own object model in Python ?

See my [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546803/qt-and-python-how-to-find-objects-and-use-them).

Comment: Could you clarify what objects you are referring to?

Comment: In link above I represented one of those problems. But for example, in one (main window) class I have scene for which want want to make class Shapes (ie) as separate class. In these class I wan to make Rectangle group of objects so that should be callable like: Shapes.triangleOne or Shapes.triangleTwo etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are asking how to traverse a Qt object tree. See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#details

> QObjects organize themselves in object trees. When you create a
>   QObject with another object as parent, the object will automatically
>   add itself to the parent's [children](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#children)() list. The parent takes ownership
>   of the object; i.e., it will automatically delete its children in its
>   destructor. You can look for an object by name and optionally type
>   using [findChild](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#findChild)() or [findChildren](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#findChildren)().

EDIT:
`QGraphicsItem`, however, is not a subclass of `QObject` and does not have an `objectName` property. If you need to access such objects by name, you must do it by yourself, for example using a Python `dict` with names as keys and objects as values.

Comment: I made a link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546803/qt-and-python-how-to-find-objects-and-use-them) in my question above with example and exact problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Alex I'm afraid I don't understand what the question is.

Comment: Upvotes and excuses for mine misundersanding.I made app: http://www.3lectronics.com/stripboard-schematic-layout-editor/stripboard-layout-and-schematic-free-editor.svg . Now I'm trying to make desktop app as this one. When put resistor in scene i want to access to all graphic components of it; lines, circles... So every instance of it has to be callable as well as its graphic components and attributes. Javascript allows me to refer at any of them like document.getElementsByClassName("resistor").lastChild or document.getElementsByTagName("g")[0].getElementsByClassName("resistor").lastChild....

Comment: Or document.getElementById("resistorOne").getElementsByTagName("circle")[0].getAttributes("x")...
I believe that should be (and in more elegant way) done with PySide.

Comment: @Alex If you are specifically asking about `QGraphicsItem`s in a `QGraphicsScene`, see edited answer.

Comment: That's the answer I need. Thank you. If I understand you well, it means that data which are stored in dictionary would have pointers to item instances in scene?